# Decomposition of Lefschetz fibrations into surface bundles and Lefschetz fibrations over spheres

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry, differential-topology, symplectic-topology

Assume that $M$ is a Lefschetz fibration with fiber genus $g$ over a base of genus $h>0$ (with at least one singular fiber).  What obstructions exist to decomposing $M$ into a surface bundle $S$ of fiber genus $g$ and base $h$ and a Lefschetz fibration $N$ over $S^2$ such that $N$ takes all of the singular fibers of $M$?  This decomposition is meant as follows:  We can recover $M$ as a fiber sum of $N$ and $S$.

Assuming there were no obstructions, one would be able to build a Lefschetz fibration over $S^2$ which has a single singular fiber (using an example constructed by Korkmaz/Ozbagci), contradicting results of Stipsicz.

Comment: If you take a disk $D$ in the base that contains the critical image, the boundary of $D$ should have trivial monodromy in order to have such decomposition. There is a decomposition as that you are asking for iff you can find such a disk. A Lefschetz fibration over $S^2$ with only one singular fiber is possible only if the vanishing cycle is homotopically trivial in the fiber.